# jScript Magnifier - on hover

Tags: javascript, html

Hope one of you can help and really appreciate it!

I have found an image magnifier on Dynamic Drive, but it's not exactly what I want.. it's perfect except for one thing. I don't want the user to CLICK on the image to view it, I want them to just be able to hover over it and the image enlarges on the middle of their screen. I have tried a few others such as this one:
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/css3_hover_image_gallery/

If anyone has a link to one that is like what I am looking for, or can get the imagemagnify one to work on hover that would be perfect!

Here is the link to the one I like:
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/imagemagnify.htm

Thank you all for answers!

Comment: What is it about the first solution you posted (that enlarges an image on hover) that you don't like? It seems to meet all the requirements you mentioned, which are to magnify the image and only do so on hover. EDIT: Also, why is this question tagged "jscript"?

Comment: I don't like how you have to click on the image to magnify it. I only want to be able to hover over it and it enlarges. Also it's tagged as jscript because some of the magnifiers and hover zooms are written with jscript.

Comment: And the one that I linked with the hover and enlarge doesn't work as the enlarged image is so close to the other images. So the other images are ontop of the enlarged image.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any other plugins that do what you're requesting, but it looks like you may be able to just edit the source code they provide for your own purposes since it's not minified.

To change it so that it enlarges the image on hover instead of click, you can just change the appropriate parts that handle clicking to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

For example, you can change the following line...

```
$target.bind('click.magnify', function(e){ //action when original image is clicked on
```

to this...

```
$target.bind('mouseenter.magnify', function(e){ //action when original image is hovered over
```

Note: You would probably want to give them credit for the original code if you do so.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this out. And ofcourse all original credits will be left. Thanks!

Comment: It kind of works, but not exactly how I wanted it too; this is not your fault! Thanks for your reply though, it worked, just a little buggy!